# Dispose of resources used by 3rd party class which does not implement IDisposable

Tags: c#

I'm using a 3rd party assembly to provide sftp functionality to my project as shown below.
Multiple threads need to implement this functionality so the 3rd party assembly is consumed in a static helper class.

The 3rd party assembly works well unless an unusual error condition is encountered, e.g. the sftp server exists but the directory I'm attempting to put files into gets deleted.
When this happens a valid exception is thrown however it appears that intermittently the 3rd part assembly isn't cleaning up after itself correctly as no new instances of the client will work.

```
static readonly object _locker = new object();

    static void WorkerMethodCalledByThread()
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            var client = new ThirdPartyAssembly();
            bool hasConnection = false;
            try
            {
                client.Connect("some connection details");
                hasConnection = true;
                // do some work - 
                //but if an issue happens here then no new instances of ThirdPartAssembly work
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Logger.LogError(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hasConnection) { client.Close(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no means to get the 3rd party assembly changed so what I'm looking for is a way to dispose of any resources it may have taken. However the 3rd party class being called does not implement IDisposable itself.

So.. I'm trying to figure out if its possible to release the resources used by the 3rd party ?

The two possible approaches I can think of are either

1: add a wrapper class which has the 3rd party class as its base class & which also implements IDisposable (shown below) - however I'm pretty sure this won't clean up the base class

2: use a WeakReference to the 3rd party class (shown below) - but I don't know if this will work

Wrapper Class

```
public class WrapperClass : ThirdPartyClass, IDisposable
{
    ~WrapperClass()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

WeakReference

```
static readonly object _locker = new object();

    static void WorkerMethodCalledByThread()
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            var client = new WeakReference(new ThirdPartyAssembly());
            bool hasConnection = false;
            try
            {
                ((ThirdPartyAssembly)client.Target).Connect("some connection details");
                hasConnection = true;
                // do some work - 
                //but if an issue happens here then no new instances of ThirdPartAssembly work
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Logger.LogError(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hasConnection) { ((ThirdPartyAssembly)client.Target).Close(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the third party class has internal resources that need to be disposed, I'm not sure how using a weak reference will help unless _your_ code has memory leak issues and is still referring to the old object. If you know the internal resources/methods that the third party library uses to dispose, you might be able to leverage reflection to get at those private members to perform your own manual cleanup.

Comment: instanceOfThirdPartyClass = null; Doesn't helps?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with the `WeakReference` is:

> while still **allowing that object to be reclaimed by garbage collection.**

it doesn't guarantee that GC will get to it because it clearly isn't managing itself well internally.

The better approach is to base the class and implement `IDisposable`. This will allow you to leverage your wrapper in a `using` statement. However, the caveat is this, and there's really no way around it, you're going to have to use `Reflection` to dig into this class and clean it up.

It's going to take a lot of breakpoints, and a lot of digging in the `Watch` windows, but you can get it done!